# How to create and push DetailView of a update feed item in navigationController stack when action button in notification is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, ios-4.2, apple-push-notifications

I am working with a nav based app. which parse a feed and shows data in tableView. every cell in tableView creates a DetailView when its clicked. I am working now with push notifications. My question is that when i get a notification, it has two buttons, view and ok. when i click on view, it launches the app. but shows the tableView which is not updated. I want my app to parse the feed again and show the new item's detailView when i click on view. is it possible? if it is then how can i do that? i tried to parse feed again and create a detailView in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but i couldn't. Can any body tell me how to do that? thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

Inside the userInfo dictionary should be the details you pass, hopefully providing what you need to present the detail view.

I am not sure what you mean by "i couldn't" but you do have to tell your TableView to "reload" once its been presented.  Without some source code, its difficult to diagnose the exact problem.  Best of luck!

Comment: i read that when we click action button in notification this is called application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and this method is in AppDelegate.m . how can i access RootViewController methods from there. can i access RootViewController methods like this: RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init]; 
  [controller startParsing];   or not. i am sorry i m quite new in objective c and its confusing little bit that how can i access other class methods and vaiable. thanx